# Unable to Publish Azure Data Factory Publish

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to pulish an Azure Data Factory pipeline, however I'm getting the error:

> Error The document creation or update failed because of invalid
> reference 'master'. Please ensure 'master' exists in data factory mode
> and recreate it in Git mode if already present.

[image]

I am familiar with the error. However, I'm can't find reference 'master'. Can someone let me know how to go about tracking down the reference 'master'?

Thanks

Comment: I can tell you from deep experience that Publish errors in ADF/Synapse are just the worst. Have you switched to Live mode to search for something named "master" there?

Comment: Hi Joel, it’s absolutely terrible - really terrible. Yes, I’ve searched in Live mode and nothing. It’s driving me crazy, as I’m unable to Trigger or Schedule pipeline runs without publishing them first - really annoying.

Comment: OK, the next thing I would do: go to your Git repo > workspace_publish branch > {workspace_name} folder. Download the "TemplateForWorkspace.json" and search for "master" there.

Comment: Hi Joel, I checked that folder, and nothing. I've open a support request to Microsoft

Comment: Did you get a resolution on the support ticket?

Comment: Hi @MartinJaffer-MSFT, Microsoft never came back to me with a resolution .. totally ignored my ticket. It looks like you work for Microsoft. If I give you the ticket number will you be able to follow up for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is commonly caused by a mismatch between Data Factory mode and Git mode. It may happen when Git is first configured, or when changes are added directly in Git or in Live mode.

If you are unable to find and fix the conflict manually, you may re-sync the content in the Git Configuration page, by using either:

- Overwrite Live Mode (which I recommend): Makes Data Factory mode (published) version match Git.
- Import Resources: Makes a Git branch match Data Factory mode.

[Git configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LduB4.png)

Please be advised that overwriting live mode may result in losing changes not currently in Git. You may use Import Resources to persist changes prior to this.