# ADF Publish Fail - Invalid references or dependencies found

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, branch, repo

I am working on creating ADF pipelines and whenever I am publishing my pipeline changes I am keep getting this error -

*Invalid references or dependencies found. This is likely due to publishing outside of Git mode or editing and deleting linked services in other branches. To recover from this state, please refer to the errors below and our Git troubleshooting guide*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwOMx.png)

I have tried disconnecting Repo and connected back using both options of checking & unchecking the "import existing resources" checkbox. After I connect back i get no error at once but then for any new changes all my publish is giving me this error.

SOME HISTORY :

Before this starting happening I attempted merging the two branches (master to dev , dev was my collaboration branch) but that merging ended up removing my 3 pipelines from dev and it just replicated my master to dev. I revert that "merge". Since then I noticed I am getting this Publishing error.

I am on a time crunch & have a project delivery. Really need help in this.

I expect no publishing error.

Comment: Can someone help me with this issue ?

Comment: can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761942/unable-to-publish-azure-data-factory-publish) once?

Comment: Hi Bhavani - Thank you so much for your help. Overwrite Live Mode option works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Invalid references or dependencies found. This is likely due to publishing outside of Git mode or editing and deleting linked services in other branches. To recover from this state, please refer to the errors below and our Git troubleshooting guide
```

@Marco Aurélio Bigélli Cardoso, thanks for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761942/unable-to-publish-azure-data-factory-publish). Below are the reasons for the error mentioned above:

- There is a mismatch between Data Factory mode and Git mode. This may occur when Git is first configured or when changes are added directly in Git or in Live mode.
- Overwrite Live Mode: This makes the Data Factory mode (published) version match the Git version.
- Import Resources: This makes a Git branch match the Data Factory mode.